# Increase, update and save scores in all cells UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cell

I'm creating word puzzle game with Swift 4 and I'v 300 cells, how to increase, update and save scores in all cells UICollectionView ?

**Code :**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    if indexPath.row + 1 < EnabledID {

        cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "CorrectMark"))
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        cell.cellLabel.text = ""
        QV.score += 2
        QV.lblScoreCoins.text = String(score)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(lblScoreCoins.text, forKey: "Key")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        lblScoreCoins.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Key")

    }

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let QV : QuestionView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "QuestionView") as! QuestionView
    QV.idFromCollection = indexPath.row + 1

    self.present(QV, animated: true, completion: nil)

    QV.lblScoreCoins.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Key")


}
```

Comment: I suppose in your datasource collection you are holding a data object of some kind for each cell. Save your score etc. for each cell there and make the cells display the score from the data object. Then all you have to do is call reloadData to update all cells.

Comment: Do not modify cell properties rather only modify your datasource and call reloadCell for any particular cell. Your all cells are not used rather only displayed  cells are resused on screen

Comment: How can I do that ? @Wasserfloh

Comment: OK, what's the best solution ? @ahmed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution, in class ViewController write this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let score = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "ScoreCoins")
    lblScoreCoins.text = String(score)

}

func addScore() {

    var score = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "ScoreCoins")
    score += 1
    UserDefaults.standard.set(score, forKey: "ScoreCoins")
    lblScoreCoins.text = String(score)

}
```